# Does the Sealdah-Puri Duronto Express train have regular sleeper coaches?

Tags: india, sleeping, indian-railways

The Duronto express trains have mostly AC coaches. Are there also any normal sleeper coaches on it?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting "unclear" close votes.  The question formulation could be improved but all the information is there.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, Sealdah - Puri Duronto Express consist of both *Normal Sleeper Coaches* and *AC Sleeper Coaches*.

For further info you can search for Train No. 22201 on Indianrailinfo or go to the following [link](http://indiarailinfo.com/train/seats/reservation-availability-sealdah-puri-duronto-express-22201/16814/325/217)

Comment: You obviously understood what OP is asking; could you please then edit the question to something understandable by everyone, so that it can be useful to other people? Thx :-)

Comment: Thx, much appreciated :-)

Comment: It was my first time editing, so did it a couple of times, will improve in future, welc :)